# Stir a pot / pan- its exact meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'd like to know what kind of action is described by "stirring a pot / pan."
Does it necessarily mean moving an object, e.g. a spatula, among pieces of food in the pot / pan? If someone is moving a pan up and down without turning the food with an instrument in  the pan, can we say he or she is "stirring a pan"?

The Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary defines stir as:

> [transitive] to move a liquid or substance around, using a spoon or something similar, in order to mix it thoroughly

Other learner's dictionaries, including Longman, Oxford, Cambridge, Collins Cobuild, and Merriam Webster, all say sitrring is an action involving the use of a spoon or other object, [such as](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/stir):

> [+ object] : to mix (something) by making circular movements in it with a spoon or similar object

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you aren't interested in the idiomatic expression *stir the pot* but just want to know which actions count in the definition of "stirring"? If so, most dictionaries have some pretty good examples. If someone moves a pan in a circular motion causing the contents to be mixed, it counts as stirring. However, I wouldn't typically say they were *stirring the pan*. I'd say they were stirring whatever was in the pan (e.g., *stirring the soup*). I'm not saying it's wrong, I just don't think it's common, not in my part of the world, at least.

Comment: I would never scoff at Oxford, but it's always a good idea to look at more than one dictionary. I think definition 2 in Merriam-Webster gets at the most basic essence of stir's meaning: *to disturb the relative position of the particles or parts of especially by a continued circular movement* BTW, the downvote was not from me.

Comment: Well, that is the most common way to stir something, I suppose. I usually try to avoid having to stir my coffee by just putting the cream in the cup before the coffee, but if I forget to put the cream in first, I often try to stir my coffee by just swirling it about in my cup. :)

Answer (score 2):

"Stirring the pot" means to stir the liquid in the pot. Usually you'd do this with a spoon.

"Stirring the pan" is not an idiom or phrase I've ever heard used. It doesn't have any particular meaning and I advise you to avoid using it.

The reason one is idiomatic and the other is not is that usually a pot is a larger vessel, and when we cook liquids like soup we do that in a pot. While it's true that liquids can be cooked in some kinds of pans (like a *saucepan*), if we stir those liquids, we'd normally say we're "stirring the sauce" or "stirring the gravy" or whatever, not "stirring the pan".

Comment: And yes, if you're sauteing onions in a fry pan, you can stir those too. That's "strirring the onions", and still not "stirring the pan".

Answer (score 2):

The expression "stir the pot" may be used to mean "stir the contents of the pot". It is more likely to be being used figuratively: the phrase [means](https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/7/messages/204.html) "unsettle and provoke arguments". The imagery is of a broth, with all the ingredients settled at the bottom. You stir it to get them unsettled. How you stir it (spoon, stick, ladle, or just swirling) is not important, since it is being used metaphorically.

> Jack suggested that Pete was cheating on Jane, just because he likes to stir the pot.

Nowadays "pots" (made of ceramic) are rarely used for cooking, nearly all cooking is done in metal pans, which may be high sided (saucepan) or low sided (frying pan). The phrase "stir the pot" is common enough that, even when using a pan, people might say "stir the pot". I am sure people also say "stir the pan", "stir the jug" and so on, although it would be arguably more correct to say, for example, "stir the soup". It doesn't always require a tool, but normally one would use a spoon or a stick for example.

Comment: The point is that this is a figurative expression. There is no real pot.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply swirl the contents round the pan, the appropriate term depends on **why** you are doing it.

If you are heating something in a pan, you just want to move it around a bit so that it doesn't burn. If you don't have a suitable stirring implement handy, so you swirl the contents, you could think of it as stirring the contents, but not stirring the pan. This does not match definition 1 in the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stir), but it does match definition 2.

I have seen Thai cooks mixing the contents of a wok using a vigorous upward and forward motion, similar to tossing (flipping) a pancake. This is definitely mixing without a utensil, but again it's the contents that's stirred, not the wok.

If, after frying something, you add a little water and swirl it around to get all the flavour from the pan in order to make sauce with the water, it's definitely not stirring: the correct term is deglazing.

Doubtless there are other reasons to swirl that might have different names.

Comment: The Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary defines stir as: [transitive] to move a liquid or substance around, using a spoon or something similar, in order to mix it thoroughly. However, it seems you can "stir" the contents without using a utensil.

Comment: @Apollyon, see definition 2 in the link in my answer.

Comment: Definition 2 on the page is not about cooking.

Comment: @Apollyon, It doesn't say that it can't be used about cooking :-)

Comment: When food is "stirred" without an instrument in a pan, is it necessarily stirred slightly, as implied by that definition?

Comment: @Apollyon, It is certainly causes a lot less movement than stirring with a spoon.

Comment: If a Chinese cook moves a wok up and down, there is bound to be lots of movement.

Comment: @Apollyon I would probably call the action tossing. The resulting dish could still be a stir fry.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to know what kind of action is described by "stirring a pot / pan." Does it necessarily mean moving an object, e.g. a spatula, among pieces of food in the pot / pan?

I'd be careful about thinking any word in English "necessarily" means anything. Most words can be stretched a little bit in the right context. But words do often have "normal" and "usual" meanings.

First of all, we don't normally "stir the pan", we stir what's in the pan ([interesting ngram on that](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stir%20the%20pan%2Cstir%20the%20onions%2Cstir%20the%20sauce%2Cstir%20the%20coffee%2Cstir%20the%20paint&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3)). However, sometimes the expression "stir the pan" means just that – stir what's cooking in the pan – as it does in this online recipe:

> Towards the end you will need to **stir the pan** constantly to ensure that the vegetables do not scorch.

Given that statement along your question about spatulas and spoons, I'd ask, "What else would you stir the veggies with?"

Of course, any competent chef knows there are *other* ways to keep vegetables moving in a pan without using a spoon (you can [toss them](http://www.seriouseats.com/2014/07/how-to-toss-food-skillet.html), for example). I might be more inclined to call this tossing movement *flipping* rather than *stirring*, but I wouldn't cry foul if someone said:

> With a deft flick of his wrist, the chef stirs the simmering mushrooms in the melted butter.

[image]
Ergo, no spatula necessary.

In short, I can stir a drink with my finger. I can stir ketchup and mustard together using a french fry. Unsurprisingly, I can stir my coffee using a coffee stirrer and my paint with a paint stirrer. But I can stir up trouble with nothing at all.

Which brings me to your other expression, *stir the pot*. As James mentioned in his answer, this expression doesn't usually refer to cooking at all, but to a metaphorical pot. [*Stirring the pot*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stir_the_pot) is not unlike [*stirring a hornet's nest*](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/stir-up-a-hornet-s-nest), and either one of those could be considered a rough antonym of [*letting sleeping dogs lie*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/let+sleeping+dogs+lie). (Typically, when we use those expressions, there are no literal dogs, no literal hornets, and no cauldron over a literal fire – just an instigator and a *[can of worms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/can+of+worms)*.)

As a footnote, it's interesting to see what happens to that [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stir%20the%20pot%2Cstir%20the%20onions%2Cstir%20the%20sauce%2Cstir%20the%20coffee%2Cstir%20the%20paint&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) when you change "stir the pan" to "stir the pot".